# List all SPWorkItemJobDefinition

Tags: timer-jobs, integration

I have a document that I would like to delete, but receive the following error message: "This list item has a job pending."

I believe this is caused by our TRIM Integration creating `SPWorkItem`s on it. I would like to be able to see all job definitions for work items, but there doesn't seem to be any public methods/properties which expose these, without requiring a Guid.

The only "get" method anywhere that I can find is `SPSite.GetWorkItems`

This post declares that there is nothing public in the objcet model, and recommends looking at the database: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/161aa906-9662-4673-a6d6-0a5b6e5dd8f4/can-i-get-spworkitem-for-document-conversion-job?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy I obviously don't want to do that.

Am I missing something? Are there any methods/properties in the object model that I can use to list the `SPWorkItemJobDefinition`s and their type ids so that I can then get the `SPWorkItem`s and see what's wrong with them?